# Reuse custom directive to make sortable table in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap in my project. I have created a table following the link (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples). This table has sortable and searchable features. Following the example from link (https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/table-complete.ts) I have created a table in my project. This example has a custom directive for sorting the table. The code is given below:

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { IncomeHeadListModel } from "../_models/income-head-list.model";

export type SortColumn = keyof IncomeHeadListModel | '';
export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';
const rotate: {[key: string]: SortDirection} = { 'asc': 'desc', 'desc': '', '': 'asc' };

export interface SortEvent {
  column: SortColumn;
  direction: SortDirection;
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()'
  }
})
export class NgbdSortableHeader {

  @Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';
  @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
  @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

  rotate() {
    this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
    this.sort.emit({column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction});
  }
}
```

In this directive I have to pass a model (**IncomeHeadListModel** ) to make the field sortable. The line is:

```
export type SortColumn = keyof IncomeHeadListModel | '';
```

Now I want to reuse the same directive for another table. That table use another model which is: **ExpenseHeadListModel**. How can I pass this another model in the below line:

```
export type SortColumn = keyof IncomeHeadListModel | '';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution would be to ease the typings and just use a string for column names.

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { IncomeHeadListModel } from "../_models/income-head-list.model";

export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';
const rotate: {[key: string]: SortDirection} = { 'asc': 'desc', 'desc': '', '': 'asc' };

export interface SortEvent {
  column: string;
  direction: SortDirection;
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()'
  }
})
export class NgbdSortableHeader {

  @Input() sortable: string = '';
  @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
  @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

  rotate() {
    this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
    this.sort.emit({column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction});
  }
}
```

There could be a better solution leveraging generics and inferring the type from the parent component or context. Or with providing the type as an input property. I'm not sure if it's possible thought.